# Memory leak in stringByAppendingString

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsstring

```
NSString *strURL=@"http://cache.finn.no/mmo/";
strURL=[strURL stringByAppendingString:soapResults];
[arrMainImages addObject:strURL];
```

My last two lines are causing memory leaks? Here, the variable `soapResults` is of type `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet above looks fine regarding how you are using `strURL` - how do you actually know that there are leaks occuring in those lines?

You might want check though that you are releasing `soapResults` and `arrMainImages` properly if you took ownership of them.

Comment: @devaditya: Hm, then you need to show more context / give more information.